# Deleted Constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have been following this video series about concurrency and the guy just started talking about critical sections. We made a template class called 'auto_lock'(I'll just include the troublesome parts:

```
class auto_lock
{

    T& m_lock;
public:
    auto_lock(auto_lock& const) = delete;
    auto_lock(auto_lock&&) = delete;
    auto_lock& operator=(auto_lock& const) = delete;
    auto_lock& operator=(auto_lock&&) = delete;
    auto_lock(T& lock) throw() :
        m_lock{ lock }
    {
        m_lock.enter();
    }
};
```

I am also having the same error with this class (once again I am only including the troublesome sections of code):

```
class critical_section
{
    CRITICAL_SECTION m_lock;

public:

    critical_section(critical_section& const) = delete;
    critical_section& operator=(critical_section& const) = delete;
    critical_section& operator=(critical_section&&) = delete;
    critical_section(critical_section&&) = delete;

    critical_section() throw()
    {
        InitializeCriticalSection(&m_lock);
    }
};
```

In my main function:

```
int main()
{
    auto lock = critical_section {}; //error here
    {
        auto guard = auto_lock<critical_section>{ lock };//and here
    }
};
```

The specific errors are '"critical_section::critical_section(critical_section &&)" (declared at line 42) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function' and '"auto_lock::auto_lock(auto_lock &&) [with T=critical_section]".'
What do I do?

Comment: Do `auto_lock<critical_section> guard{lock}`

Comment: Putting a `critical_section` on the right side of an `=` simply does not make any sense.

Comment: `auto_lock& const` and `critical_section& const` should be either 1) `const auto_lock &` and `const critical_section &`, or 2) `auto_lock const &` and `critical_section const &`, respectively. The original code is taking const-references to non-const objects, whereas you instead need references (const or non-const) to const objects.

Comment: You could make your class moveable, I don't see any reason not to. THen the original syntax would work

Comment: @M.M: And how would you *safely* move a `CRITICAL_SECTION` struct instance and reset the instance being moved from? Microsoft does not provide an API to do that. If you want the `critical_section` class to be movable, you would have to dynamically allocate the `CRITICAL_SECTION` and then you can move that pointer around.

Comment: @RemyLebeau OK, that's a good reason

Answer (score 4):

This is where Almost Always Auto fails, since these types are non-copyable and non-moveable.

```
int main()
{
    critical_section lock{};
    {
        auto_lock<critical_section> guard{ lock };
    }
}
```

(if you don't like this, wait for C++17 mandatory copy elision to be implemented)

Why does this require a copy? Because while this code is unlikely to make a copy, a copy/move constructor still must be accessible in order for the code to work. And `auto lock = critical_section{};` is the same as `critical_section lock = critical_section{};`

Comment: "*`auto lock = critical_section{};` is the same as `critical_section lock = critical_section{};`*", which is the same as `critical_section lock{critical_section{}};`, which is copy/move-construction with a temporary object as input.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it's copy/move construction  (in this case, neither copy nor move, since there is no accessible constructor for either option)

Comment: Thank you, but I still don't understand how there is no error in his code. Is he using a different version, or would that even matter?

Comment: @deadbird11: there is a big difference between `auto lock = critical_section {};` and `critical_section lock{};`.  The first way default-constructs a temporary object (which succeeds since that constructor is not deleted) and then copy/move-constructs `lock` from the temporary (which fails because that constructor is deleted). The second way only default-constructs `lock` directly with no temporary involved.

Answer (score -1):

If you trace what the code does

```
auto guard = auto_lock<critical_section>{ lock };//and here
```

calls

```
auto_lock::auto_lock(T& lock)
```

which attempts to construct `m_lock` with `lock` calling

```
critical_section::critical_section(critical_section&&)
```

which was deleted.

Comment: In `auto_lock`, the `m_lock` member and the `lock` constructor parameter are both declared as `T&`, so `m_lock{ lock }` is not constructing `m_lock` as a `T` object, it is assigning a reference to point at the existing object passed to the `auto_lock` constructor.

Comment: `auto lock = critical_section {};` is trying to copy-construct `lock` from the temporary object created by `critical_section {}`, but the copy constructor is deleted.

Comment: I think you are basically talking about the same thing.

Comment: You said "*`auto_lock::auto_lock(T& lock)` **which attempts to construct** `m_lock` with `lock` **calling `critical_section::critical_section(critical_section&&)`**,*" which is simply not true because there is no construction taking place, simply assigning one reference to another, so `critical_section(critical_section&&)` is not being called like you claim. It is not the same thing, it is a big difference.